When is a person referred to as a 'scout'?
One meaning of the word scout is "Informal An individual; a person: a good scout" according to the American Heritage Dictionary, 4th ed.
I wonder in what context is this meaning used and what are its connotations?

In collaborative software development, we say that someone is a "good scout" when they leave the system in a neater and more orderly state than when they found it.  The analogy is presumably to how a Boy Scout is urged to leave each environment they pass through as unspoiled by their presence as possible.

Great to know! I've written software for 20+ years and never heard of "good scout" on the job. I guess that says about the collective, or, in the case I missed it, my own awareness.

It isn't widely used and has an American, folksy connotation. I recommend you don't use it unless you're familiar with scouting and American culture, and even then, it would be used rarely.
The Scouts (also known as Boy Scouts) are a movement of children and young adults aged 10-18, traditionally boys but now girls and non-binary youths are admitted. They take part in outdoor and charitable activities, and are known for their professed values of resourcefulness, sense of duty, respect for others, etc. They form an international society united by shared experiences and values, and even after leaving an adult ex-scout would be expected to still have some of the same virtues.
"Scout" in this sense is normally used only in the expression "a good scout", or variants of that, according to Merriam-Webster which says under "scout (noun)": "4  INDIVIDUAL, PERSON — used chiefly in the phrase good scout".
"Good scout" means someone with the virtues of a scout. Merriam-Webster labels "a good scout", "US, informal + somewhat old-fashioned" with the definition "a person who is friendly, kind, helpful, etc." To unpack that, it's primarily in American English, and you'd expect to hear it in older colloquial-English sources, maybe old films, TV, and books, not among urban youth.
However it was occasionally used on its own as a term of address. It might be used in the boy scouts to address another member, and using it outside the scouts suggests a similar atmosphere of male confraternity (especially in past times when boyhood was a bit more traditional). Wiktionary gives the quote:

"Listen, old scout," Mr. Osborn said solemnly, "you think New York is heartless, but that's not what it is."

This is from Robley Wilson's book of stories Dancing for Men (1983). it's not clear when the story is set, but Osborn is offering advice in a friendly way, as between two members of the brotherhood of boy scouts.

Why did you mention urban? Are rural youth different?

Some rural youth in the US are differnt.

'A good egg' is synonymous, and more clearly metaphorical.

@commenters I'd stick with 'Are rural youths ...' or 'Is rural youth ...'.

"Old scout" isn't really "scout" per se.  Isn't it like "old bean"?  You wouldn't call someone "bean" without "old".

@EdwinAshworth Why "youths"?  The singular with plural sense is well attested. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22rural+youth+are%22&rlz=1CATMUU_enUS1067&oq=%22rural+youth+are%22&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOdIBCTc3NzhqMGoxNagCCLACAQ&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

@TimR The usage '[The] youth [of America] are ...' is certainly on the increase, but 'some youth are' is forcing a count usage that I've only seen condemned. [LanguageTips]

Nowadays, in the sense you quote from the dictionary, only when their personhood is canine. It's a name for a dog, like "Spot". The word is not used as a term of address for non-scouts (in the Boy Scouts context), and nobody has said, "Hey, scout, where is the refreshment stand?" since probably the 1960s, when it was more or less synonymous with "young fellow", a way an older man might address a youngster at a middle school fundraising event.
You will see it, I think, in children's cartoons whose scripts don't seem to have been written by native speakers of English.
